# NodeJS asynchronous issues: I am getting a different order everytime when fetching a document from Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

There is no problem with this code but it is changing the order of documents every time.

I have placed console.log(id) just after the for loop to check the order in the array and its fine there,

```
 async.each(Array, function (id, callback) {
                    console.log(id); // same as array order
                    Pcard.findById(id)
                        .populate(
                            {
                                path: 'UserTags',
                                model: 'User',
                            },
                            {
                                path: 'Like',
                                model: 'User'
                            }
                        ])
                        .exec(function (err,finalres){
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err);
                            } else {
                                **console.log(finalres._id); // But here id are not in same order** 
                                arr.push(finalres);
                                callback();
                            }
                        });
                }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(200).send({
                            'error': 'Some err has occurred',
                            'status': false
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.status(200).send({
                            'results': arr,
                            'status': true
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

How do I maintain the order of documents in every output as it is in the array?

These 3 id's are stored in MongoDB in the same order and these are the console.log outputs of statement which is just inside the for loop:

```
5957bcd393ea02554c4e63f3
5957bd177e996b56d08b991a
5957bd742c830457192ba66d
```

This is the result of the second console.log statement console.log(finalres._id):

```
5957bcd393ea02554c4e63f3
5957bd177e996b56d08b991a
5957bd742c830457192ba66d
```

This time the output is in same order as the id's in array

Consider this case for the same:

```
 5957bcd393ea02554c4e63f3
 5957bd177e996b56d08b991a
 5957bd742c830457192ba66d
```

Here the order is not the same:

```
5957bcd393ea02554c4e63f3
5957bd742c830457192ba66d
5957bd177e996b56d08b991a
```

What needs to be done to preserve the order every time?

Comment: Hi Kartik, welcome to SO. Please try to format your questions properly and have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't you need to pair `async` with `await`? I would think you'd do something like `await Pcard.findById(id)`.

Comment: This crashes my app adding await Pcard.findById(id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`async.map()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map), which will both maintain order and collect all the results (instead of having to use a separate array to push the results into):

```
async.map(array, function(id, callback) {
    Pcard.findById(id)
      .populate(
        {
          path: "UserTags",
          model: "User"
        },
        {
          path: "Like",
          model: "User"
        }
      )
      .exec(callback);

      /* 
        The line above is a shortcut for this:

         .exec(function(err, finalres) {
           if (err) {
             callback(err);
           } else {
             callback(null, finalres);
           }
      */
  },
  function(err, arr) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(200).send({
        error: "Some err has occurred",
        status: false
      });
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({
        results: arr,
        status: true
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Be aware that this will start `array.length` *concurrent* queries to your database. If `array` is sufficiently large, you can create an I/O bottleneck using this code.

You can replace `async.map()` with [`async.mapLimit()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit) to limit the number of concurrent queries, if this becomes a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: But there is no error handling here ! If one of Document is not able to populate, Does it Automatically throws error?

Comment: @kartikkhandelwal there _is_ error handling, and it should be the same as for your previous code. However, I took a shortcut with the code that may not be clear. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hey if i update my code like Pcard.findOne('_id' : id, 'flag': true,) then if my flag is not true in one document then i am getting null in array of result !                So how do i remove that null value ???

Comment: i am using filter right now but i am not able to filter my data !

Comment: @kartikkhandelwal I'd assume that this should work: `arr.filter(function(item) { return item })`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are going through array and for each item sending a request to mongodb. As you are doing async requests library is probably doing concurrent jobs. So some jobs (requests to mongodb) can finish faster and are returned before others. That's why the order is changed. It's not order of items in array, is order of responses that got back from mongodb.

You can read explanation [here in Async documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

I'm not familiar with Async library so i can't help you with which method to use to maintain order. If you would use Bluebird you could use [each](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/each.html)

*TIP:
Also, mongoose supports promises, which is much better then callbacks. I recommend you use promises instead as it makes code more readable.*

EDIT: You could use [map](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) which returns array of responses that should be in correct order.